# Select max of each group with its associated values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a large table formatted like so:

```
+-----+-------+-------+
| id  | count | group |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 123 | 37    | a     |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 121 | 26    | a     |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 442 | 33    | a     |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 923 | 55    | b     |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 783 | 12    | b     |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

My goal output would select the max count as well as the id associated with the max count for each group. Is there an array function that can do this? This array function gets me the max count, but it's not always distinct so i'm unsure how to grab the id as well:

```
{=MAX(IF(C:C=C1,B:B))}
```

So this would check the group in the 3rd (C) column and return the max count in the 2nd (B) column, but how can i grab the first (A) column as well?

Comment: It's not clear what sort of output you want. Possibly a pivot table would return your desired results.

Comment: As @RonRosenfeld mentioned, by pivot table (having group as row, and count as value) you can get the maximum of count. Then by `Lookup` find the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want.  In the example below

```
F2:  =MAXIFS(count,group,E2)
G2: =INDEX($A:$A,MAX((group=E2)*(count=F2)*ROW(id)))
```

and the formula in G2 is an array formula which must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Of course, if you don't have `MAXIFS` in your version of Excel, and you don't like to use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> sequence, you can use these formulas instead:

```
F2: =AGGREGATE(14,4,(group=E2)*count,1)
G2: =INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(14,4,(count=F2)*(group=E2)*ROW(id),1))
```

[image]

Comment: No worries for the CSE, it's was used "with some pleasure" in the OP :)

Comment: ah! simply grab the group and max, then index match the results! why didnt i think of this before :) thanks Ron!

Comment: @A.S.H True, but others sometimes look for solutions.

Comment: also not sure what ash meant by 'cse' but the reason i was looking for a function is because i'm writing this as part of a larger program in VBA.